# Calculate maximum of next 3 rows of a particular column in each row in Python

Tags: python, pandas, max

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    seq                         score
0   TAAGAATTGTTCTCTGTGTATTT     -23.19
1   AAGAATTGTTCTCTGTGTATTTC     -3.67
2   AGAATTGTTCTCTGTGTATTTCA     -16.49
3   GAATTGTTCTCTGTGTATTTCAG     -11.83
4   AATTGTTCTCTGTGTATTTCAGG     -10.86
5   ATTGTTCTCTGTGTATTTCAGGC     -7.24
```

I want to select 3 rows in a loop and then get maximum value of the score.

The result I am looking for is like this:

```
    seq                          score
1   AAGAATTGTTCTCTGTGTATTTC     -3.67
5   ATTGTTCTCTGTGTATTTCAGGC     -7.24
```

I tried applying groupby function and sort, but it does not seem to work as the seq column has unique values.

What other method can I use to get such result?

Comment: Hi Ranu! Could you please reformat the data in your question to make it more legible for us? As of now it is hard to tell what belongs in which column.

Comment: Also, is this a limited pattern, or do you want to calculate it with a shifting POV? Like:
you have 15 blocks of Pattern = (digit, string, float) and you want to always grab blocks 0-2, 1-3,2-4,3-5 etc. or just blocks 0-2, 3-5, 6-8 etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for index of max value per groups created by integer division of index by `3` and then seelct rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby(df.index // 3)['score'].idxmax()]
print (df)
                       seq  score
1  AAGAATTGTTCTCTGTGTATTTC  -3.67
5  ATTGTTCTCTGTGTATTTCAGGC  -7.24
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.index // 3)
Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype='int64')

print (df.groupby(df.index // 3)['score'].idxmax())
0    1
1    5
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'seq':['TAAGAATTGTTCTCTGTGTATTT','AAGAATTGTTCTCTGTGTATTTC','AGAATTGTTCTCTGTGTATTTCA','GAATTGTTCTCTGTGTATTTCAG','AATTGTTCTCTGTGTATTTCAGG','ATTGTTCTCTGTGTATTTCAGGC'],
                   'score': [-23.19,-3.67,-16.49,-11.83,-10.86,-7.24]})
df = df.loc[df.groupby(df.index // 3)['score'].idxmax()]
print(df)
```